# Int session variable to increment?

Tags: c#, session, variables, session-variables

Can a session variable be an `int`? I want to increment  `Session["PagesViewed"]+1;` every time a page is loaded. I'm getting errors when trying to increment the session variable.

```
if (Session["PagesViewed"].ToString() == "2")
{
     Session["PagesViewed"] = 0;
}
else
{
     Session["PagesViewed"]++;
}
```

Comment: What are the errors you're getting?

Comment: You need to make sure you are not in a webfarm. If so, verify that you have shared session.  Also, kind of off topic, but google analytics does this for you and probably more efficiently.

Comment: `Session["PagesViewed"]++;` is basically the same as `((object)Session["PagesViewed"])++;` and is not legal.

Answer (score 8):

You need to test to see if the `Session` variable exists before you can use it and assign to it.

You can do increment as follows.

```
Session["PagesViewed"] = ((int) Session["PagesViewed"]) + 1;
```

But, if the `Session["PagesViewed"]` does not exist, this will cause errors.  A quick `null` test before the increment should sort it out.

```
if (Session["PagesViewed"] != null)
    Session["PagesViewed"] = ((int)Session["PagesViewed"]) + 1;
```

Comment: That won't compile. You need to explicitly add the `1`: `Session["PagesViewed"] = (int)Session["PagesViewed"] + 1;`

Comment: Should probably use `++` as a prefix since it does an assignment first as a postfix and so the value will not change. `Session["PagesViewed"] = ++((int)Session["PagesViewed"]);`

Answer (score 3):

`Session["PagesViewed"]` will only return an Object - which is why your `.ToString()` call works.  You will need to cast this back to an int, increment it there, then put it back in the session.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, it can be. However, `++` only works when the compiler *knows* the object is an int. How does it know that some other part of your code doesn't sneakily do `Session["PagesViewed"] = "Ha-ha";`?

You can effectively tell the compiler that you won't do something like that by casting: you'll get a runtime exception if the session variable isn't really an int.

```
int pagesViewed = (int)Session["PagesViewed"];
if (pagesViewed == 2)
{
    pagesViewed = 0;
}
else
{
    pagesViewed++;
}
Session["PagesViewed"] = pagesViewed;
```